# shell command that eats its input if it matches a string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I’m looking for a shell command (a one-liner) that eats all of its standard input if that input matches a string. Otherwise, it just outputs its input.

Likewise, how about a command that eats all of its input if it *doesn’t* match the string.

Presumably sed or awk can do it, but it’s beyond my fu. I can easily do it with a shell script but I’d prefer a single command.

This is useful in crontab so that you only receive an email if the output of a command fails (i.e. matches a string).

So, below, what are “eatIfMatch” and “eatIfNoMatch”?

Thanks for any ideas.

```
$ cat matchFile
This file
will match the
pattern
$ cat noMatchFile
This file
doesn’t quite
Match
though
$ eatIfMatch match < matchFile
$ eatIfMatch match < noMatchFile
This file
doesn’t quite
Match
though
$ eatIfNoMatch match < matchFile
This file
will match the
pattern
$ eatIfNoMatch match < noMatchFile
$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed and Bash):

```
eatIfMatch(){ sed -zn '/'"$1"'/!p' "$2"; }
eatIfMatch match fileMatch
eatIfMatch match fileNoMatch
This file
doesn’t quite
Match
though
eatIfNoMatch(){ sed -zn '/'"$1"'/p' "$2"; }
eatIfNoMatch match fileMatch
This file
will match the
pattern
eatIfNoMatch match fileNoMatch
```

Function `eatIfMatch` accepts regexp to match and if it does eats the file.
Function `eatIfNoMatch` accepts regexp to mat and if it does not eats file.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the input to a variable. Check if the variable contains the string. If not, it prints the string.

```
eatIfMatch() {
    local var=$(cat)
    if [[ $var != *"$1"* ]]
    then printf "%s\n" "$var"
    fi
}
```

If you want `awk`, it's essentially the same logic

```
awk '/match/ {found=1} {all = all "\n" $0} END {if(found) print substr(all, 1)}'
```

Comment: Thanks, Barmar. As I said, I can do it with a script (or, as you suggest, a function). But I'd rather a sed or awk command.

Comment: They'll pretty much have to do the same thing -- save all the input in a variable, then check whether it contains a match for the word.

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to do it with sed, since it only operates one line at a time.

Comment: I think you could append all the input lines to the hold space, compare the hold space against the pattern, and swap the hold and pattern spaces if they match. But as to how to actually do it, ... ?

Comment: I added an `awk` solution

Comment: That's the eatIfNoMatch version. Use if(!found) to get the eatIfMatch.

A slight improvement... instead of "print all", use "print substr(all, 2)" to avoid an extra newline prepended.